# Difficulty with boolean list function

Tags: javascript

Write a function named "find_value" that takes a list of integers as a parameter and searches for the value 6. The function will return a boolean value representing true if 6 is in the list and false if it is not. (My code below)

```
function find_value(integers){
    for (var i of integers){
        if (i == 6 in integers){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When inputing a list like [0, 1, 6], I should get the expected value as true but I end up getting false instead. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an actual value of the array by taking [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Then you need to check against the value, better with [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and return `true`, but not `false`, because it would end the iteration and the function.

Move the last `return false;` statement outside of the loop, before the function ends.

```js
function find_value(integers) {
    for (var i of integers) {
        console.log(i); // just check the value
        if (i === 6) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(find_value([0, 1, 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this(You don't need to return when it is not found.):

```js
function find_value(integers){
    for (var i of integers){
        if (i == 6){
            return true;
        }
    }
}

console.log(find_value([0,1,6]));
```

Or what you can do is something like this:

```js
function find_value(integers){
    var valueHolder = [];
    for (var i of integers){
         if (i == 6){
             valueHolder.push(true);
          }
          else {
              valueHolder.push(false);
          }
       }
       
    return valueHolder;
}

console.log(find_value([0,1,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my humble solution for any int array and any searched number:

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
             
  var arr = [1, 2, 6];
  get_six_from_array(arr,6);
  
  function get_six_from_array(arr,num){

  console.log(arr.includes(num));

  if(arr.includes(num)){
        return true;}
     else{
        return false;
    }
  
  }
};
```